# Parse JSON as array of objects instead of dictionary using Codable in Swift

Tags: json, swift, parsing, codable, decodable

I receive the following JSON from API

```
{
   "someProperty":"someValue",
   "type":"type1",
   "values":{
      "first":"someValue",
      "second":"someValue" // keys and values are always different !
   }
}
```

I created model to parse this JSON and it works.

```
struct MyModel: Codable {
    let someProperty: String
    let type: SomeType
    var values: [String: String]?
}

enum SomeType: Codable {
    case type1, type2
}
```

But I need to get array of objects instead of dictionary. Because I need to get values in right order.

I want something like this:

```
struct MyModel: Codable {
    let someProperty: String
    let type: SomeType
    var values: [Value]?
}

enum SomeType: Codable {
    case type1, type2
}

struct Value: Codable {
    let key: String
    let value: String
}
```

And I don't understand what should I change in my code to make this model works. Because now I get error "Expected to decode Array but found a dictionary instead."

Is there a way to parse JSON like I want?
Any suggestions? Maybe example of code with similar parsing

Thanks for your time and your help!

Comment: Is there a correlation between `type` and the content of `values`? And what are those keys in `values`, are they limited to a set of keys or can they be anything?

Comment: Depending on type, values can be nil. Keys in "values" can be anything

Comment: It seems there is a library that can parse the JSON in given order -> [github](https://github.com/mikezs/Tisander)

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't use libraries

Comment: If the keys in `values` can be anything then you need to use a dictionary

Comment: *I need to get values in right order.* What order, if the keys could be anything? And you can even order the stuff after decoding the dictionary.

Comment: In JSON I have 
"values":{
      "first":"someValue",
      "second":"someValue"
   }

And I need to get array of objects or just array of keys in the same order ["first", "second", "third", "etc"]

Comment: A dictionary is unordered by definition and you cannot sort `["first", "second", "third", "etc"]` in any programming language in the human meaning.

Comment: I've understood. I thought that properties in JSON has an order, but then I realized that this is also a dictionary which cannot be ordered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a custom init. In it decode the dictionary and map it into an array of your `Value`:

```
struct MyModel: Codable {
    let someProperty: String
    let type: SomeType
    var values: [Value]?

    enum CodingKeys: CodingKey{
        case someProperty, type, values
    }
    
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        
        someProperty = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .someProperty)
        type = try container.decode(SomeType.self, forKey: .type)
        
        let dictionary = try container.decodeIfPresent([String:String].self, forKey: .values)
        values = dictionary?.map{Value(key: $0.key, value: $0.value)}
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it works! But using dictionary I'm losing the correct order in the array of values. Is there a way to keep the correct order?

Comment: @Nik No, Dictionaries are unsorted by default. You could sort them yourself after mapping, if the sorting is known.

Comment: Is there a way to get just array of keys without values? And then use them to access values in dictionary?
Something like this:
let arrayOfKeys = try container.decodeIfPresent([String].self, forKey: .values)

Comment: @Nik The only thing you could do is to provide your own deserializer. Use the library I linked under your question as a base.